# Can we send data to an espresso test

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

So I am implementing a custom idling resource and I am wondering, is it possible to have the UI send data to espresso tests with data about is causing my idling resource to increment?

Can I create another callback that is run when my IdlingResource is idle that sends to my test?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to send?